# Flask-SocketIO Emit message and sent not working. (ValueDuplicationError)

Tags: socket.io, flask-socketio

I am using Flask-SocketIO(version: 5.0.1) in the backend and in the front end using socket.io (version 4.0.1).
Backend code:

```
@socketio.on('connect')
def socket_connect():
    print(f"connected***** {request.args}")
    emit('my-response', {'data': 'Connected flask backend'}, room=f"room{request.sid}")
```

Here the print statement worked but emit is not working.
After few seconds I get this error

```
bidict.ValueDuplicationError: ODpLc2T7oBppyH-VAAAX
```

Front end Js code:

```
socket.on("connect", function() {
    console.log("connn ");
})
```

when I checked the console the socket status looks like this:

```
connected: false
disconnected: true
```

In the Flask command if I removed the emit statement then in the console the socket connection status becomes like this:

```
connected: true
disconnected: false
```

Comment: I solved it. The issue was with this message queue. I added localhost rabbitmq and deployed it in Heroku after removing the message queue it worked fine.
In answer, I am adding complete backend and client-side socket code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask (Sever Side):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask_socketio import send, SocketIO, emit, join_room

app = Flask(__name__)

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

@socketio.on('connect')
def socket_connect():
    print(f"connected***** {request.args}")
    emit('my-response', {'data': 'Connected from flask'}, room=f"room{request.sid}")

@socketio.on('join')
def joined(data):
   print(f"***on_join*** {data}")
   join_room(room)
   send(f"{request.sid} has entered the room.", room=data['room'])

@socketio.on("my-event")
def client_event_response_trigger(json):
    print(request.args)
    print(request.json)
    socketio.emit("my-response", json)

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def socket_disconnect():
    print(f"Disconnected: {request.args}")
```

Client-Side:

```
socket_con_query
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000/", {query: "if needed then add the querystring"})

socket.on("connect", function() {
    console.log("connecting")
    socket.emit("join", {room: "room"+socket.id, sid: socket.id})
    socket.emit("my-event", {"test": "tesing"})
})

socket.on('my-response', function(msg) {
    console.log("received: ", msg)
    socket.emit("my-event", {"test": "Demo"})
    })
```